# Perl: Reverses the first 'N' number of words in given input line using the substitution operator. Leave the spacing unchanged

Tags: regex, perl

I'm a beginner in Perl Pattern Matching.

Facing problem in Solving below question.

Write a program that reverses the order of the first 'N' number of words in given input line using the substitution operator. Leave the spacing unchanged.

Below program is reversing till the last word! I can't able to restrict the substitution operator to break @ Nth word.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$str = "Test TEST   test  tesT tESt";
$str =~ s/(\w+)(\s*)/reverse($1) . $2/ge;
print $str . "\n";
```

Can any one please help me in solving this using substitution operator?
Is it really possible to restrict @ Nth word using substitution operator?

Comment: Input => "Test TEST   test  tesT tESt". if we want to reverse first three words. Output => "tseT TSET tset tesT tESt".

Comment: Can't you just split, reverse the order, and re-place?

Comment: Actually I want to do that only using substitution methodology in pattern matching. like, $str =~ s/(\w+)(\s*)/reverse($1) . $2/ge;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of count and decide on value of `$i` whether to reverse `$1` or not,

```
my $str = "Test TEST test tesT tESt";

my $i = 0;
$str =~ s/(\w+)/ ++$i <3 ? reverse($1) : $1 /ge;

print $str, "\n";
```

output

```
tseT TSET test tesT tESt
```

Comment: Just added little more stuff to fulfill 'Leave the spacing unchanged' requirement: 

$str =~ s/(\w+)(\s*)/ ++$i <=$n ? reverse($1) . $2 : $1 . $2 /ge;

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is to do this in 2 steps.

Create an array of words by using

```
\b(\w+)\b
```

Output:`['Test', 'TEST', 'test', 'tesT', 'tESt']`

Now from the given array lets say the no of words is `3`.

So you can create a new list starting from index `2` of array backwards and appending the rest of elements from index `3`..

Then you can cast it to a string.

Comment: `/(\w+)/g` is good enough on its own. Without any other pattern to interfere, it will always have a `\b` before (or else it would have started matching sooner) and after (or else it would have matched more).